# C# Keeps forgetting my progress

Tags: c#

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(sName + ".txt", true)) 
{
       iDayNum++; //Adds a day on each time that case 3 is used.
       Console.Write("How many minutes have you been exercising? ");
       iExcerMinutes = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); 
       Console.WriteLine();
```

The code inside here works fine but when I reopen the program and ask the program what daynumber I am on it resets, what am I missing?

Comment: Where did you write this number to your text file? I don't see any code to do that.

Comment: Your variables are not saved automatically, you will have to write anything you want saved to a file yourself.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? im desperate

Comment: Check out [MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter(v=vs.110).aspx) for System.IO.TextWriter. Also, save your variables to somewhere (file, database).

Comment: Firstly decide where you want to save it.  Sensible options would be a text file, a settings file or a database.

Comment: - and - don't lose heart.  Programming takes a lot more time to get to grips with than you expect.  What I showed you in my example below contains a whole load of magic-automatic functionality so you do not have to worry, but you still need to set aside a lot of time to get to grips with the logic of what you are trying to achieve.  Keep calm and carry on

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help get you started - one technique is as follows.

Right-click your project, select properties/settings and create a `user-scope` setting.

I just created one called 'RunCount' of type int with value zero in a console application - I set the access modifier to 'public', as it happens.

The following code persists the run count incrementing it as it goes.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        Settings.Default.RunCount += 1;
        Settings.Default.Save();

        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("This is run number {0} for this user", Settings.Default.RunCount));  

        Console.WriteLine("Press a key to continue");
        Console.ReadKey();  
    }
}
```

If you were to run this example, then have a look in `c:\users\"yourname"\Appdata\Local\"yourprogramname"` you will find a .config file containing :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <userSettings>
        <yourprogramname.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="RunCount" serializeAs="String">
                <value>1</value>
            </setting>
        </yourprogramname.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```